# Is it possible to have voltage across an inductor without having current through it?

Tags: voltage, transformer, inductor

Example : In certain cases in transformers we do assume so having zero current in the secondary but there is still a voltage across it due to mutual flux .

Also we do similar things while calculating the thevenin equivalent of the secondary in the tranformer circuit .

Answer (score 2):

Instantaneously, yes.  But that voltage will cause the current to ramp up according to the standard equation: \$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}\$

In other words, Voltage determines the *rate-of-change* of Current, which could easily pass through zero on its way to (theoretical) infinity.

(Theoretical because all inductors also have some resistance, which will ultimately limit the current to the standard resistive equation: \$V=IR\$)

Answer (score 1):

A coil of wire will have a voltage induced that is proportional to the rate of change of magnetic flux (and the number of turns). Recall the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation). This flux may be created internally or externally.

Many practical inductors are shielded so that the induced voltage from external flux is minimized, but it is not going to be zero unless you've got it stuck inside a superconducting cavity.

Comment: Agreed , But it should indeed produce a current shouldn't it ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the induced voltage from the field change equals any externally applied voltage (or the coil is open) then no current will flow.

Comment: Thanks @Spehro Pefhany i might come back to this question again with a diagram tomorrow ! :D

Answer (score 0):

If the secondary winding of a transformer is open-circuit there cannot be a current through it, but there is a voltage across it. An (ideal) inductor cannot support a voltage without a changing current through it.

Comment: That is absolutely what my doubt is ! How is that possible ? having a secondary side voltage without any changing current through it !

Comment: It's like having a voltage generator (eg a battery) with nothing connected to it

Comment: The sinusoidal primary current sets up a sinusoidal flux in the transformer core. This changing flux creates a sinusoidal induced voltage in the secondary. If there is a load connected to the secondary a current will flow, if there's no load then the current is zero. It's not possible for an isolated inductor to have a voltage across it when there's not a changing current flowing through it because there's nothing to create a changing flux. This assumes 'ideal' conditions where the windings have zero resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since current is nothing more than the flow of charge, and since a magnetic field passing through a conductor will move electrons around in that conductor, that constitutes current.

Consequently, if there's an induced abundance of electrons on one end of the conductor and a paucity on the other, a voltage difference will exist between the ends of the conductor.